# Jupyter notebook throws SyntaxError: invalid syntax on correct input

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write a function that creates a request object for Elastic Search. Here's my code,

```
URL = 'http:localhost:4443/'
def get_request_object(row):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    data = [{"update": "id:prism:prismaggregation:g={}:{}".format(row.ownerid, row.mediaid), "create": true,
             "fields": {"mediaid": {"assign": {"".format(row.mediaid)},
                        "ownerid": {"assign": {"".format(row.ownerid)}},
                        "storyid": {"assign": {"".format(row.storyid)}}}}]
    #data.append(payload)
    response = requests.post(URL, data=data, timeout=5)
    return response
```

I'm reasonably sure this code block is syntactically correct. However when I run it on a jupyter notebook, I get the following error,

```
File "<ipython-input-12-630242a1363f>", line 7
    "storyid": {"assign": {"".format(row.story_id)}}}}]
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It isn't syntactically correct. Add an extra closing `}`. I can't test beyond that because I don't have any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra } at line 5 (second line here):

```
data = [{"update": "id:prism:prismaggregation:g={}:{}".format(row.ownerid, row.mediaid), "create": true,
         "fields": {"mediaid": {"assign": {"".format(row.mediaid)}},
                    "ownerid": {"assign": {"".format(row.ownerid)}},
                    "storyid": {"assign": {"".format(row.storyid)}}}}]
```